ImportXML Query- Unable to retrieve data from a website
enter image description hereI am trying to retrive number of products appearing just below the brand name using ImportXML. But I am getting error "Imported Content Empty"
Code I am using is =IMPORTXML("https://www.nykaafashion.com/designers/puma/c/4886?searchType=SearchedFromHistory&internalSearchTerm=Puma","//*[@id="app-container"]/div[2]/div[2]")
Link:"https://www.nykaafashion.com/designers/puma/c/4886?searchType=SearchedFromHistory&internalSearchTerm=Puma"
Trying to retrieve nos of products- Refer the attached Picture.
Please help resolve.
Regards
Formula Used: IMPORTXML("https://www.nykaafashion.com/designers/puma/c/4886?searchType=SearchedFromHistory&internalSearchTerm=Puma","//*[@id="app-container"]/div[2]/div[2]")

No picture attached

@rockinfreakshow   Please find the picture link https://i.sstatic.net/5JiYv.jpg


You may try with the following xpath:
//*[@data-at='plp-product-count']

